# How can I use the OAuth2 Middleware to get Data from external API

Tags: c#, oauth, oauth-2.0, .net-core

On my .NET Core MVC Webapp the User must to login with my Own Open Id Connect Provider.

The OIDCP is built with the Django Package "[django-oidc-proider](https://django-oidc-provider.readthedocs.io/en/v0.5.x/index.html)". My Api is secured with OAuth2 and now I want to access Data behind the Api via the C# `HttpClient` but I always get an `Unauthorized` back. That’s makes sense because the Request don’t have the necessary Headers.

**Question:**
How can I use the OAuth2 Middleware to get Data from external API

**More Information about the .NET Core MC App:**

1. I'm using Cookie based Authentication
2. I'm not using the IdentityFramework

Comment: Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Add `Authorization` HTTP header like below

```
Authorization: Bearer {access-token}
```

to your request. I don't think you have to use any middleware to do this simple thing. I guess that `HttpClient` provides a method to set HTTP headers. See [2.1. Authorization Request Header Field](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6750#section-2.1) in RFC 6750 for details as to how to pass an access token to API.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But how can I get the AccessToken from my Middleware?

Comment: I believe anyone who read your question thinks that you have already obtained an access token. How to get an access token depends on which authorization flow you use.